# Confused about the notation $||\nabla u||_{L^p(\Omega)}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

I am reading *Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations*, by Haim Brezis, and also Evans' *PDE*. I am confused about what  $||\nabla u||_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}$ precisely means. In these two books it is often written, like for example in the Sobolev, Gagliardo and Nirenberg inequality, which states that:

$$ || u||_{p^*} \leq C ||\nabla u||_p $$

The book defines $\nabla u=(u_{x_1},..., u_{x_n})$, so it is a **vector**. But the book also defines the L^p (And Sobolev $W^{1,p}$) spaces as those formed by functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, and the norm by integrating that function.

> Is there a *standard* meaning for $||\nabla u||_{W^{1,p}(\Omega)}$?

Because, for example, I have checked in the proof of $ || u||_{p^*} \leq C ||\nabla u||_p $ that it means that $||u||_p$ is bounded by the product of the $L^p$ norms of the derivatives of $u$. But if we check the proof of Proposition 9.3, we have, at a certain step, for $h \in \mathbb{R}^n$:

$$\int_0^1 |\nabla u(x+t)|^p dt$$

How does one interpret that integral? I understand taking the absolute value of a vector could mean take the absolute value of every component in that vector, but integrating a vector? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Means that $\partial_{x_j} u \in L^p(\Omega)$ $\forall j=1,...,n$, i.e. $\nabla u \in L^p(\Omega) \times \cdot \cdot \cdot \times L^p(\Omega)$.

Comment: And $\int_0^1 |\nabla u(x+t)|^p dt$? Does it mean $\int_0^1 |\partial_{x_i}u(x+t)|^p dt$?

Comment: $\forall i=1...n$, yes, It is just a notation.

Comment: Understood. Thanks.

Comment: I don't get the inequality, since it doesn't take in account the (possibly unbounded) integration constant. what does mean $\|u\|_{p^*}$ ? or we consider that $\Omega = \mathbb{R}^n$ in that case the integration constant is constrained to be $0$ for $\|u\|_p$ to be finite ? @D1X

Comment: It has not been said, but I think it is assumed that $\Omega$ is limited

Comment: Mmmm, not necessarily. I have a proposition proved also for $\mathbb{R}^n$

Comment: @JohnMartin It really confuses me that the book also defines at certain proofs $Du$ as any partial derivative of $u$ (Explicitly saying it) and does not do it for $\nabla u$.

Comment: things can be just those two, they are only notations.

Comment: @JohnMartin Can you provide me any reference where this is explicitly said? Thanks.

Comment: But I think it is explained in each book, see for example the definition of weak derived. Also in Brezis

Comment: Brezis does not explain it, although I can rearrange the proofs and statement so that they don't use this notation.

Comment: For example, see page 263.

Comment: I can only find there the definition of $\nabla u$.

Comment: There is also $g_i = \partial_i u \in L^p$, then it is clear that the gradient is in the product space.

Comment: But the question was about  the fact that whenever you write $||\nabla u||_{p}$ you are integrating a **vector**.

Comment: It is a notation, mean what you wrote in the first comment.

Comment: I understand that, I was only asking for a reference where that is generally stated. Thanks anyway for your time.

Comment: @JohnMartin Sorry to bother you again, but checking the proofs of these theorems the only thing that now makes sense to me is: $||\nabla u||_p= ||\partial_{x_1}u||_p+...+||\partial_{x_n}u||_p$. Otherwise, in page 268 (Proof of Proposition 9.3) there are no means to obtain the desired result (iii).

Comment: $|\nabla u |^p = (\sqrt{\partial_1 u^2 + ... + \partial_n u^2})^p$

Comment: The rest depends on the notation that uses the book, you can also wait for the partial derivative directly, using the projections.

Comment: Do you mean with  $|\nabla u |^p $ $||\nabla u ||_p$? And is it $(\sqrt{\partial_1 u^2 + ... + \partial_n u^2})^p$ or $(\sqrt{\partial_1 u^p + ... + \partial_n u^p})^p$?

Comment: $| \cdot |^p \neq || \cdot ||_p$